# Java library for URL encoding if necessary (like a browser)

Tags: java, urlencode

If I put the `http://localhost:9000/space test` URL to the address bar of a web browser it calls the server with `http://localhost:9000/space%20test`.
`http://localhost:9000/specÁÉÍtest` will be also encoded to `http://localhost:9000/spec%C3%81%C3%89%C3%8Dtest`.

If put the encoded URLs to the address bar (i.e. `http://localhost:9000/space%20test` and `http://localhost:9000/spec%C3%81%C3%89%C3%8Dtest`) they remain the same (they won't be double-encoded).

Is there any Java API or library which does this encoding? The URLs comes from the user so I don't know if they are encoded or not.

(If there isn't would it be enough to search for `%` in the input string and encode if it's not found, or is there any special case where this would not work?)

***Edit:***

`URLEncoder.encode("space%20test", "UTF-8")` returns with `space%2520test` which is not what I would like since it is double-encoded.

***Edit 2:***

Furthermore, browsers handle partially encoded URLs, like `http://localhost:9000/specÁÉ%C3%8Dtest`, well, without double-encoding them. In this case the server receives the following URL: `http://localhost:9000/spec%C3%81%C3%89%C3%8Dtest`. It is same as the encoded form of `...specÁÉÍtest`.

Comment: Use `URLEncoder.encode()` method?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[What every web developer must know about URL encoding](http://blog.lunatech.com/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding)

[Url Encoding Explained](http://www.freeformatter.com/url-encoder.html)

**Why do I need URL encoding?**

```
The URL specification RFC 1738 specifies that only a small set of characters 
can be used in a URL. Those characters are:

A to Z (ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ)
a to z (abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz)
0 to 9 (0123456789)
$ (Dollar Sign)
- (Hyphen / Dash)
_ (Underscore)
. (Period)
+ (Plus sign)
! (Exclamation / Bang)
* (Asterisk / Star)
' (Single Quote)
( (Open Bracket)
) (Closing Bracket)
```

**How does URL encoding work?**

```
All offending characters are replaced by a % and a two digit hexadecimal value 
that represents the character in the proper ISO character set. Here are a 
couple of examples:

$ (Dollar Sign) becomes %24
& (Ampersand) becomes %26
+ (Plus) becomes %2B
, (Comma) becomes %2C
: (Colon) becomes %3A
; (Semi-Colon) becomes %3B
= (Equals) becomes %3D
? (Question Mark) becomes %3F
@ (Commercial A / At) becomes %40
```

**Simple Example:**

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class TextHelper {
    private static ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager()
        .getEngineByName("JavaScript");

/**
 * Encoding if need escaping %$&+,/:;=?@<>#%
 *
 * @param str should be encoded
 * @return encoded Result 
 */
public static String escapeJavascript(String str) {
    try {
        return engine.eval(String.format("escape(\"%s\")", 
            str.replaceAll("%20", " "))).toString()
                .replaceAll("%3A", ":")
                .replaceAll("%2F", "/")
                .replaceAll("%3B", ";")
                .replaceAll("%40", "@")
                .replaceAll("%3C", "<")
                .replaceAll("%3E", ">")
                .replaceAll("%3D", "=")
                .replaceAll("%26", "&")
                .replaceAll("%25", "%")
                .replaceAll("%24", "$")
                .replaceAll("%23", "#")
                .replaceAll("%2B", "+")
                .replaceAll("%2C", ",")
                .replaceAll("%3F", "?");
    } catch (ScriptException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TextHelper.class.getName())
            .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, +1! It works fine but encoding and decoding some special characters smells a little bit for me and not too easy to understand. Anyway, I couldn't find any case where it fails, so I accept your solution. Thank you again!

Comment: "%2F" for "/" is missing

Comment: Seems to be missing `{` and `}` as well..

Answer (score 8):

Use the java [`java.net.URLEncoder#encode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

```
String page = "space test";
String ecodedURL = "http://localhost:9000/" + URLEncoder.encode(page, "UTF-8");
```

Note: encoding the complete URL would result in an undesired situation, for example `http://` encodes in `http%3A%2F%2F`!

**Edit**: to prevent encoding an URL twice you could check whether the URL contains a `%` as it is only valid for encodings. But if a user wrongly messes up the encodings (like, only encode the URL partially or use a `%` in an URL without it being used for encoding something) then there is not much to do using this method...

Comment: Thank you, especially for pointing out the partially encoded case. Browsers handle these cases too. (I've updated the question with this one.)

Comment: This answer solves the problem for above use case because there is no path with multiple segments. If we wanted to solve this generically, we would have to split the path at the dashes and extract all path segments, then encode each segment separately, in order to prevent the dashes from being encoded.

Answer (score 4):

Finally, I've checked what Firefox and Chrome do. I've used the following URL with both browsers and capture the HTTP request with netcat (`nc -l -p 9000`):

```
http://localhost:9000/!"$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```

This URL contains every character from ASCII 32 to 127 except `[0-9A-Za-z#]`.

The captured request is the following with Firefox 18.0.1:

```
GET /!%22$%&%27()*+,-./:;%3C=%3E?@[\]^_%60{|}~%7F HTTP/1.1
```

With Chrome:

```
GET /!%22$%&'()*+,-./:;%3C=%3E?@[\]^_`{|}~%7F HTTP/1.1
```

Firefox encodes more characters than Chrome. Here is it in a table:

```
Char | Hex    | Dec     | Encoded by
-----------------------------------------
"    | %22    | 34      | Firefox, Chrome
'    | %27    | 39      | Firefox
<    | %3C    | 60      | Firefox, Chrome
>    | %3E    | 62      | Firefox, Chrome
`    | %60    | 96      | Firefox
     | %7F    | 127     | Firefox, Chrome
```

I've found some code in their source tree which does something similar but I'm not quite sure that these are the actually used algorithms or not:

- Chrome: http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/net/base/escape.cc?revision=HEAD&view=markup
- Firefox: `toolkit/components/url-classifier/nsUrlClassifierUtils.cpp`

Anyway, here is a proof of concept code in Java:

```
// does not handle "#"
public static String encode(final String input) {
    final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (final char c: input.toCharArray()) {
        if (shouldEncode(c)) {
            result.append(encodeChar(c));
        } else {
            result.append(c);
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}

private static String encodeChar(final char c) {
    if (c == ' ') {
        return "%20"; // URLEncode.encode returns "+"
    }
    try {
        return URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(c), "UTF-8");
    } catch (final UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}

private static boolean shouldEncode(final char c) {
    if (c <= 32 || c >= 127) {
        return true;
    }
    if (c == '"' || c == '<' || c == '>') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Since it uses `URLEncoder.encode`, it handles `ÁÉÍ` characters as well as ASCII characters.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Scala code snippet. This encoder will encode non-ascii characters and reserved characters in the URL. Also, as the operation is idempotent, the URL won't be double-encoded.

```scala
import java.net.URL
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers

object IdempotentURLEncoder extends RegexParsers {
  override def skipWhitespace = false
  private def segment = rep(char)
  private def char = unreserved | escape | any ^^ { java.net.URLEncoder.encode(_, "UTF-8") }
  private def unreserved = """[A-Za-z0-9._~!$&'()*+,;=:@-]""".r
  private def escape = """%[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}""".r
  private def any = """.""".r
  private def encodeSegment(input: String): String = parseAll(segment, input).get.mkString
  private def encodeSearch(input: String): String = encodeSegment(input)
  def encode(url: String): String = {
    val u = new URL(url)
    val path = u.getPath.split("/").map(encodeSegment).mkString("/")
    val query = u.getQuery match {
      case null      => ""
      case q: String => "?" + encodeSearch(q)
    }
    val hash = u.getRef match {
      case null      => ""
      case h: String => "#" + encodeSegment(h)
    }
    s"${u.getProtocol}://${u.getAuthority}$path$query$hash"
  }
}
```

### Example usage(test code)

```scala
import org.scalatest.{ FunSuite, Matchers }

class IdempotentURLEncoderSpec extends FunSuite with Matchers {
  import IdempotentURLEncoder._

  test("Idempotent operation") {
    val url = "http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/文字"
    assert(encode(url) == encode(encode(url)))
    assert(encode(url) == encode(encode(encode(url))))
  }

  test("Segment encoding") {
    encode("http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/文字")
      .shouldBe("http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97")
  }

  test("Query string encoding") {
    encode("http://qiita.com/search?utf8=✓&sort=rel&q=開発&sort=rel")
      .shouldBe("http://qiita.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&sort=rel&q=%E9%96%8B%E7%99%BA&sort=rel")
  }

  test("Hash encoding") {
    encode("https://www.google.co.jp/#q=文字")
      .shouldBe("https://www.google.co.jp/#q=文字")
  }

  test("Partial encoding") {
    encode("http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/français")
      .shouldBe("http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fran%C3%A7ais")
  }

  test("Space is encoded as +") {
    encode("http://example.com/foo bar buz")
      .shouldBe("http://example.com/foo+bar+buz")
  }

  test("Multibyte domain names are not supported yet :(") {
    encode("http://日本語.jp")
      .shouldBe("http://日本語.jp")
  }
}
```

This code is from [Qiita](http://qiita.com/suin/items/ac968464f684d92b8093).

Answer (score -1):

Standard Java api's it self will do the URL encoding and decoding.

[java.net.URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html)

try the classes `URLDecoder` and `URLEncoder`

To encode text for safe passage through the internets:

```
import java.net.*;
...
try {
    encodedValue= URLEncoder.encode(rawValue, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) { }
```

And to decode:

```
try {
    decodedValue = URLDecoder.decode(rawValue, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) { }
```

Comment: the provided solution matches the one that the OP said it wasn't working well